# Como mostrar um relógio rodando os centésimos de segundos

Tags: javascript

Preciso criar um jogo que parece com um bingo.
Ele tem que mostrar um relógio rodando os centésimos de segundos .

Cada membro do jogo recebe uma cartela com vários números de 0 a 99 
e ele tem a opção de tentar parar o relógio em um número que ele tem na cartela dele.

Como faço para rodar os centésimos no php e parar quando eu apertar um botão?

Para rodar um Relógio com Horas, Minutos e Segundos, eu consegui:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
function showtime()
{ setTimeout("showtime();",1000);
callerdate.setTime(callerdate.getTime()+1000);
var hh = String(callerdate.getHours());
var mm = String(callerdate.getMinutes());
var ss = String(callerdate.getSeconds());

document.clock.face.value = 
((hh < 10) ? " " : "") + hh +
((mm < 10) ? ":0" : ":") + mm +
((ss < 10) ? ":0" : ":") + ss;

}
callerdate=new Date(<?php echo date("Y,m,d,H,i,s");?>);
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: Amigo, posta o teu html para eu te dar uma resposta melhor.

Answer (score 1):

Alterei o código para exibir os milisegundos no relógio:

```html
   <script language="JavaScript">
callerdate=new Date(2016,10,27,11,43,14);

function showtime()
{ setTimeout("showtime();",10);
callerdate.setTime(callerdate.getTime()+ 10 );
var hh = String(callerdate.getHours());
var mm = String(callerdate.getMinutes());
var ss = String(callerdate.getSeconds());
var n = callerdate.getMilliseconds();
document.clock.face.value = 
((hh < 10) ? " " : "") + hh +
((mm < 10) ? ":0" : ":") + mm +
((ss < 10) ? ":0" : ":") + ss +
":" + n;
}

function getTime(){
//clearTimeout(callerdate);
  var hora = document.clock.face.value;
document.clock.result.value = hora;
}


</script>
<body onLoad="showtime()">
<form name="clock">
<input type="text" name="face" id="clock" value="" size=15>
<input type="text" name="result" id="result" value="" size=15>
</form>

<div id="clockButton"  onclick="getTime()">Pega!</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Entao amigo,  esse é o link onde o relógio já funciona

Comment: Entao amigo,  esse é o link onde o relógio já funciona

Comment: http://www.suplementosweb.site88.net/relogio.php  preciso saber como colocar para rodar os Centésimos de segundos.   o jogador vai tentar parar o numero que ele precisa  apertando um botao..